# Count number of attachments in sharepoint 2010 list using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

I would like a piece of that would give number of attachments in a sharepoint list using jQuery. my current code gives a count of one regardless of how many I have. Please help. See my code below:

```
function PreSaveAction() {
    var count = 0;
    var elm = document.getElementById("idAttachmentsTable");
    if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0) {
        console.log(elm);
        document.getElementById("idAttachmentsRow").style.display = 'none';
        var r = confirm("some text");
        if (r == false) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
    else {
        count++;

        alert(count);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `document.querySelector('#idAttachmentsTable').rows.length;`?

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing the `count` variable just once if attachment rows are found:

```
else {
    count++;

    alert(count);
    return true;
}
```

Just use `elm.rows.length` instead to display the actual number of attachments:

```
else {
    alert(elm.rows.length);
    return true;
}
```